# what does xhr.responseXML.documentElement() do?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript. Does the above mentioned method call has anything to do with the Ajax  call?  Can anyone elaborate the above method?

Comment: Why don't you search this on Google? There are a lot of explanation out here.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.documentElement. It's not a function and it has nothing to do with Ajax. It's part of the DOM API. Spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-87CD092.

Comment: So whenever we use xhr.responseXML.document right after a particular ajax call .Will that reflect that?

Comment: For example : var accessoryAjax = new Ajax.Request("rest/SellerList", {method: 'get', onComplete: this.rendezvousSellerList.bind(this)});

Comment: I don't understand your comments.

Comment: But that call is not using variable accessoryAjax right?

Answer (score 1):

It throws a syntax error.

`responseXML` is a DOM representing the XML response received for the request.

[`documentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.documentElement) is the DOM Node for the root element of that XML document.

It isn't a function so it cannot be called.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a function, it's a DOM element. From the MDN [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.documentElement):

> Returns the `Element` that is the root element of the document (for example, the `<html>` element for HTML documents).

It has nothing to do with Ajax, it's part of the DOM API. Specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-87CD092.

`.responseXML` on the other hand is a property of the [`XMLHTTPRequest` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) with which you make the Ajax call:

> The response to the request as a DOM `Document` object, or `null` if the request was unsuccessful, has not yet been sent, or cannot be parsed as XML or HTML. The response is parsed as if it were a `text/xml` stream. When the `responseType` is set to `"document"` and the request has been made asynchronously, the response is parsed as it were a `text/html` stream.

Comment: if var accessoryAjax = new Ajax.Request("rest/SellerList", {method: 'get', onComplete: this.rendezvousSellerList.bind(this)

Comment: is followed by above method.What does that imply?

Comment: It implies nothing in particular. You simple execute one command after the other.